# How do I do a conditional join or with? Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have a model *items*.  *Items* hasMany *templateItems*.  The relationship uses *items.id* as the foreign key in *template_items*.

I am trying to return all *items* but only include the related *templateItems* where *template_items.template* equals a $id.

I have tried this;

```
        $items = Item::with('templateItems', function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('template_items.template', $id);
        })->get();
```

I get:

ErrorException in Builder.php line 1150:
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

What am I missing or is there a better way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
$items = Item::with(['templateItems' => function($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('template_items.template', $id);
  }])->get();
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!